# How to remove the fractional part from a dataframe column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Input dataframe:

```
val ds = Seq((1,34.44),
  (2,76.788),
  (3,54.822)).toDF("id","mark")
```

Expected output:

```
val ds = Seq((1,34),
  (2,76),
  (3,54)).toDF("id","mark")
```

I want to remove the fractional part from the column mark as above. I have searched for any builtin [functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#initcap-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-), but did not find anything. How should an **udf** look like to achieve the above result?

Comment: I don't suggest you to go with udf untill you can hack with inbuilt functions as done in my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `cast` to `integer` as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
ds.withColumn("mark", $"mark".cast("integer")).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+----+
|id |mark|
+---+----+
|1  |34  |
|2  |76  |
|3  |54  |
+---+----+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

**Update**

You commented as

> But if any string values are there in the column , it is getting null since we are casting into integer . i don't want that kind of behaviour

So I guess your mark column must be a `StringType()` and you can use `regexp_replace`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
ds.withColumn("mark", regexp_replace($"mark", "(\\.\\d+)", "")).show(false)
```

Comment: But if any string values are there in the column , it is getting null since we are casting into integer . i don't want that kind of behaviour

Comment: what do you want to do in that case then?

Comment: The string values or empty should be remain as it is . Can u help me

Comment: yes i want to just remove the decimals . when i tested only i realised the issue .

Comment: @adarshkadameri see my update and let me know if it doesn't work. if it does then consider upvoting too

Comment: when i used `"23.45 adarsh"` this value , 45 is replaced by empty string . my requirement is not to replace the value if it is having alphabets . @Ramesh Maharjan

Comment: can you ask another question with clear example and explanation?